# Does it make sense to pass in all the properties of a class as arguments in a constructor method?

Tags: javascript, oop

Does it make sense to pass in all the properties of a class as arguments in a constructor method?

For example,

```
class Person {     
  constructor(name, surname, age, occupation, houseAddress, maritalStatus) {         
    this._name = name;         
    this._surname = surname;         
    this._age = age;         
    this._occupation = occupation;         
    this._houseAddress = houseAddress;         
    this._maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
    /// methods...     
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is possible, but having a lot of parameters as input arguments it is considered a [bad practice](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/long-parameter-list).

As a mitigation, you can consider packing the attributes which make semantically more sense together in a struct.

On the other hand, not initialising fully an object in a constructor although you have all the data you need at construction time, is an even worse solution. Never allow an object to be unitiliasied, unless you are obliged to do so.